# If the subprocess does not call the system call, will the signal sent by kill still take effect?

Tags: c, linux

If the subprocess does not call the system call, will the signal sent by kill still take effect?

It worked. But I want to know when did the subprocess enter the kernel mode.
Code as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        while (1)
            continue;
        exit(0);
    }

    sleep(3);
    kill(pid, SIGINT);

    int wid, status;
    while ((wid = wait(&status)) != -1)
    {
        printf("child %d: exited with ", wid);
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
            printf("%d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which system call are you asking about?   Since no handler has been registered, the child terminates when the signal is received.

Comment: timer interrupt on each CPU enters kernel mode and sends signal on return.

Comment: If you want your child to wait for a signal, use POSIX [`pause()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) to do a non-busy wait.  It puts the thread to sleep until it receives a signal that has a handler installed (see the URL for the details).  It never returns 'normally'.  But it is a lot better than a `while (1) continue;` loop.

Comment: If you want to know whether the signal was delivered, check the return value of the `kill()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, processes that do not make system calls can still receive signals. You can easily test this by writing an infinite loop program, running it, then pressing Ctrl-C, or using the `kill` command from another terminal window.